# Google Fonts: Kavoon Broken In FF

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

The Kavoon font appears to be broken in FF.  It Chrome it displays as semi-bold while it displays completely differently in FF.  Example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/daneren2005/2qe35hqa/1/

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavoon&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div style="font-family: kavoon">Test</div>
```

Looking directly at https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavoon I see that there is are two different fonts embedded.  I am wondering if FF is choosing a different one than Chrome?  Does anyone have a fix for this font or should I just avoid it for now?

Error from dev console:

`17:17:14.496 downloadable font: Layout: DFLT table doesn't satisfy the spec. for script tag DFLT (font-family: "Kavoon" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2) source: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/kavoon/v4/OKJIqNlCjDLJ2zxSz-ZOtA.woff21 css:10:12
17:17:14.496 downloadable font: Layout: Failed to parse script table 0 (font-family: "Kavoon" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2) source: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/kavoon/v4/OKJIqNlCjDLJ2zxSz-ZOtA.woff21 css:10:12
17:17:14.496 downloadable font: GSUB: Failed to parse script list table (font-family: "Kavoon" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2) source: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/kavoon/v4/OKJIqNlCjDLJ2zxSz-ZOtA.woff21 css:10:12
17:17:14.496 downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Kavoon" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2) source: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/kavoon/v4/OKJIqNlCjDLJ2zxSz-ZOtA.woff21 css:10:12`

Results from https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavoon:

```
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Kavoon';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Kavoon Regular'), local('Kavoon-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/kavoon/v4/UmKWImoBBDClLUHy34euUfesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Kavoon';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Kavoon Regular'), local('Kavoon-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/kavoon/v4/OKJIqNlCjDLJ2zxSz-ZOtA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

Comment: No, there isn't. There's only one source if Firefox requests requests https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavoon, because it supports WOFF but not WOFF2, which is what you'll get (a WOFF2 subset set) if you use Chrome or another browser that has WOFF2 support. That said: yes, the version of Kavoon served to Firefox is *horribly* broken (look at your browser dev console. *lots* of errors in it), you should probably report that to Google Fonts.

Comment: I didn't see those errors because Firebug was not reporting them to me.  You are right there are errors in the native dev console though.  I submitted a feedback form for Google Fonts but I somehow doubt it will get any response since that seemed more like a "here, we will let you feel like we care" form than anything.

Comment: And loading https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavoon serves the exact same thing for both Firefox and Chrome for me.

Comment: You might be surprised how much the Google Font team cares about being on top of things. As for loadings: http://imgur.com/2QMwYQb shows FF (44.0.2) on top, Chrome below (48.0.2564.109), on my machine.

Comment: Weird because my FF 44.0.2 shows the same thing as Chrome in your image (in fact my copy paste from paste is from FF).

Comment: Opened issue on their issue tracker: https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/216